# Java : How may I add to the counter up until the limit

Tags: java

Sorry that the question is vague, I wasn't quite sure how to best word it. I have the following code so far and it works, but I wanted it to still add the amount inputted by the user. For example if the initial amount given was 4000, I still want it to add the 3000 before telling the user that it has reached maximum capacity.

```
{
       if (((var1+var2) >= 0) && ((var1+var2) < 3000)) { 
                  var1 = var1 + var2;

       }
       else{
            System.out.println("This box has reached its maximum capacity");
       }


}
```

In addition, how may I add a message telling the user that the box is nearly full, at say 2900-2999, but have it not be displayed when the box has reached its limit?

Thank you.

Comment: This code is confusing, if var1+var2 < 0 then it will display "This box has reached its maximum capacity" which doesn't really make sense right? Also, are var1 and var2 both user inputs?

Comment: var1 is the stored amount. While var2 is the user input.

Comment: You should consider giving your variables meaningful names. Also, you *could*  shorten `var1 = var1 + var2;` with `var1 += var2;`

Answer (score 0):

I will present you with a couple different options since your question is sort of vague. One option is to replace 3000 with your "amount given"

```
{
   int amtGiven = //however you obtained this value
   if (((var1+var2) >= 0) && ((var1+var2) < amtGiven)) { 
              var1 = var1 + var2;

   }
   else{
        System.out.println("This box has reached its maximum capacity");
   }


}
```

Similarly if you want to add this to existing bounds:

```
{
   int amtGiven = //however you obtained this value
   if (((var1+var2) >= amtGiven) && ((var1+var2) < amtGiven+3000)) { 
              var1 = var1 + var2;

   }
   else{
        System.out.println("This box has reached its maximum capacity");
   }


}
```

Jumping back to your original code to address your question about getting close, you should explore more options with conditional branching. In this case nested if clauses:

```
{

   if (((var1+var2) >= 0) && ((var1+var2) < 3000)) { 

       if(var1+var2 >= 2900){
            System.out.println("This box is getting close to its maximum capacity")
       }

              var1 = var1 + var2;

   }
   else{
        System.out.println("This box has reached its maximum capacity");
   }


}
```

You should also consider an alternate case for is var1+var2 < 0 as the box would not have reached its maximum capacity and thus is a special case for your program.

EDIT:

based on your comment, I think you want something to this effect:

```
{
   //this assumes maximumcapacity was defined in the constructor.
   if (((var1+var2) >= 0) && ((var1+var2) < maximumcapacity)) { 
              var1 = var1 + var2;

         //this is where you could add a bit for getting close to max capacity, see above example


   } 
   else{
        System.out.println("This box has reached its maximum capacity");
   }


}
```

Happy coding and comment if you have more questions!

Comment: Hi. Thank you for all your help. The 3000 is what's assigned in my constructor as the 'maxcapacity' . How would I display this within the code you gave >? (for ref. var 1 = stored amount. var 2 = amount user wants to add.)

Comment: I have edited my answer with what I think will work. Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

```
   int amt = var1 + var2; 
   if (amt >= 0 && amt < 3000) {  var1 += amt;  }
   if(var1 >= 2900 && <= 2999) {  System.out.println("near cap."); }
   else if(var1 >= 3000){ System.out.println("reached max cap."); }
```

Answer (score -1):

initialize var1 and var2 to zero in your program.

```
 if (((var1+var2) >= 0) && ((var1+var2) <= 3000)) { // check if the value is with in the limits 

       if(var1 >= 2900 && var1 <=2999) // check if reached maximum capacity

           System.out.println("This box has reached its maximum capacity");

           var1 = var1 + var2; // add the values based on first if condition
           }
           else{
                // to do if condition fails
           }
```

Comment: "how may I add a message telling the user that the box is nearly full, at say 2900-2999"

Comment: Since i'm not clear about in which variable he is storing the total amount. so used var1. if the total amount is nearly full , i.e from 2900-2999 it will execute the line below.